# WebApp dynamic and RT - Best start

Tags: php, jsp, web

Today i was wondering what new can i learn and i challenged myself to develop a full realtime and dynamic web app.

Basically my idea is :

- Acess webpage
- Enter a user and get a response from a webservice(JSON, the service is already done)

  e.g. : I'm receiving a JSON that contains a market cart with fruits prices and quantity
- The aplication in same page, show the return in a list.

  e.g : It'll list single blocks with the fruits,price and quantity
- This list i can remove and add items without calling another page.

  e.g. : I can remove or Add fruits to the basket, and it'll update de total price and quantity
- In the end, it would update this information to the DB

OBS : All this in the same page, in dynamic "Realtime" like in a desktop app.

Well, that doesn't sound hard, i think i could do this way simple with some PHP+HTML+MySQL+AJAX. But i think it'll be a bad written application once there's a lot of easier and more performatic frameworks.

I was searching in web seems that a lot of information like JSP, php frakeworks(zf2,codeigniter),python frameworks(django) etc..
But i would like to receive some suggestions from you guys, what you consider best to start learning.

OBS : I'm already a desktop apps and games developer.

Thank you in advance, i would be thankful if someone can help.

Comment: I think first you need to choose the language you want to work with. After choosing the language you can proceed with the framework choice.

I think the faster way to do this is with Javascript, since you could use some React(Client-Side)/Angular + NodeJs(Webservice). HTML is mandatory. Basically is that.. But there is a LOT of resources out there that you could use.

If you like PHP you still can use React/Angular on the client side, I recommend spend one/two days reading about it. I'm sure you will like it.

Comment: Thank you for your help friend. I don't think language is problem, i actually like PHP, but also like java and like python. Indeed i will spend some days reading about, but thank you for presenting me some good options. Cheers :)